# Spring Data Rest - Save parent entity with children

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, postman

I am new in Spring Data Rest. I want to save a parent entity with his children. The class are Distribution and FileIdVersion.

This is the Distribution entity.

```
@Entity
@DistributionValidator
public class Distribution extends AbstractAuditableJpaEntityImpl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull
    @Length(min = 1, max = 256)
    @SafeHtml
    private String company;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "distribution")
    @Size(max = 256)
    private List<FileIdVersion> fileIdVersions = new ArrayList<>();


    public Distribution() {
        super();
    }

    public Distribution(final String company, final String name, final String topic, final ZonedDateTime uploadDate,
            final ZonedDateTime setupDate, final UUID uuid, final List<FileIdVersion> fileIdVersions,
            final List<Bundle> bundles, final List<String> recipientId) {
        super();
        this.company = company;
        this.fileIdVersions = fileIdVersions;
    }
}
```

This is the FileIdVersion entity.

```
@Entity(name = "bundle_file_id_version")
public class FileIdVersion extends AbstractJpaEntityImpl implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull
    @FileId
    private String fileId;

    @FileVersion
    private String fileVersion;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnore
    private Bundle bundle;

    public FileIdVersion() {}
}
```

I want to save one distribution object with his fileIdVersion. I am trying something like this:

[image: Postman post of distribution]
This request only persist in BBDD one record of distribution, but not persist any records in FileIdVersion entity. How I can to persist the distribution with his file id versions? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: in the FileVersionId you are missing a distribution object and related mapping. You are using it in Distribution class via the mappedBy attribute in the annotation.
Maybe hibernate is not able to reconstruct the entity tree, and it fails

Comment: Sorry, I forget to put the distribution object in fileIdVersion class. I have this related mapping: `@ManyToOne @NotNull @JsonIgnore private Distribution distribution` Thank you.